# Appendix A instead of Chapter 1

Tags: chapters, appendices, report

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
%\chapterfont{\centering \fontsize{12}{12}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\title{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
%\includegraphics[width=]{logo}
}

\author{xxxxxxxxxxx}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{CERTIFICATE}
This is to certify that this thesis entitled, “????????????????s” embodies the work carried out by ????????????? under my supervision and that it is worthy of consideration for the award of the M.Tech(Computer Engineering) degree.\\ \\

\begin{flushright}

\textbf{
\begin{tabular}{l}
    Supervisor:\\
    Er. xxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
   Assistant Professor,\\
   Department of Computer Engineering,\\
   xxxxxxxxxx University,\\
  xxxxxxxxxx.\\
   \end{tabular}
   }
\end{flushright}

Day     Month     Year 

\chapter*{DECLARATION}
I hereby affirm that the work presented in this thesis is exclusively my own and there are no collaborators. It does not contain any work for which a degree/diploma has been awarded by any other University/Institution. A part of this work has already been published.

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\tableofcontents
\begin{appendix}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{appendix}
\chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
This is abbreviation.

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\chapter{Literature Review}
\end{document}
```

This is the code of a report I am writing; what is happening is that the instead of outpointing Chapter 1 for Introduction and Chapter 2 for Literature Review it is outputting it as Appendex A and Appendex B for Introduction and Literature Review respectively. Please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: Of course it does, since you used `appendix` right from the start

Comment: Not sure why you're using the `appendix` environment for this document. One of the things that the `appendix` environment does is to re-define `\chaptername` to say "Appendix" -- *globally*. If you simply must use this environment, I'd insert the instruction `\renewcommand\appendixname{Chapter}` *before* `\begin{appendix}`.

Comment: by the way `\linespread{factor}` is better than `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}`

Answer (score 7):

An `Appendix` belongs to the (very) end of a document, because it's appended ;-)

Using `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}` for the `LoF` and `LoT` is possible but this should be at the end then.

Since `\appendix` changes the `\chaptername` to `\appendixname` (being `Appendix` in standard setup) and also the `chapter` counter format is changed from `arabic` figures to upcase letters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[inner=4cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
%\chapterfont{\centering \fontsize{12}{12}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\title{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
%\includegraphics[width=]{logo}
}

\author{xxxxxxxxxxx}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{CERTIFICATE}
This is to certify that this thesis entitled, “????????????????s” embodies the work carried out by ????????????? under my supervision and that it is worthy of consideration for the award of the M.Tech(Computer Engineering) degree.\\ \\

\begin{flushright}

\textbf{
\begin{tabular}{l}
    Supervisor:\\
    Er. xxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
   Assistant Professor,\\
   Department of Computer Engineering,\\
   xxxxxxxxxx University,\\
  xxxxxxxxxx.\\
   \end{tabular}
   }
\end{flushright}

Day     Month     Year 

\chapter*{DECLARATION}
I hereby affirm that the work presented in this thesis is exclusively my own and there are no collaborators. It does not contain any work for which a degree/diploma has been awarded by any other University/Institution. A part of this work has already been published.

\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}

\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\input{chapters/Introduction}

\chapter{Literature Review}

\appendix
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter*{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
This is abbreviation.

\chapter{True Appendix Chapter}


\end{document}
```

Furthermore, `appendix` is a command, not an environment, at least from the `report.cls`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just removed the appendix environment because I need list of tables and figures in the beginning of report.